# Filter messages by content property

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0. I am trying to filter messages by content property using this field:

[image]

Sample message content:

```
{test:1}
```

For example I want to serach every message with `test` equal to 1.
How can I do that?

Comment: 2.17.0, so Domenico's answer is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis web console allows to browse messages on a queue and apply a filter.

Until ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15 the messages are filtered at the client side and you can use the `body` keyword to filter the messages by their content. However filtering messages at the client side is inefficient and inconsistent.

Since ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16 the messages are filtered at the broker side using a [filter](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions.html) but you can not filter the messages by their content.

ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18 will support xpath filters to filter the messages by their content, see [ARTEMIS-3137](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3137) for further details.