# ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17 Hawtio Filter search issue

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm browsing messages in the web console, and I can't filter messages based on content in their *body*. We get the following message displayed in the developer console regardless of the input:

```
[hawtio-core] Operation browse(int, int, java.lang.String) failed due to: java.lang.IllegalStateException : AMQ229020: Invalid filter:
```

I was under the influence that it worked fine with filtering on body. I'm fairly sure that it worked on 2.9 version which we had before upgrading.

Is this somewhat related to [ARTEMIS-3000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3000) which is listed as a fix in 2.17?

Comment: It does not matter what filter I'm putting in, the result is the same.

Comment: I've only tried with filters that I know would give a hit on messages currently in the DLQ. For instance, in a message containing "2e" I tried searching for this.

Comment: Body contained "2e" in this example. Allthough searching for "TEST" also gives the same error.

Comment: Hmm, I was under the influence that it worked fine with filtering on body, i'm fairly sure that it worked on 2.9 version which we had before upgrading.

Comment: Until ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15 the messages are filtered at the client side and you can use the body keyword to filter the messages by their content. See httpss://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578938/filter-messages-by-content-property/66580340#66580340

Comment: As Dom pointed out, this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66578938/filter-messages-by-content-property).

Comment: Great, thank you very much Domenico Francesco Bruscino!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reproduce this AMQ229020 error on ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 is to use an invalid filter. Your filter could contain a syntax error, ie using a double equal `AMQPriority==4`.